# Discord.py: Restarting a bot after the event loop closes

Tags: python, python-asyncio, discord, discord.py

I have a discord.py bot that I'm currently hosting locally while it matures.
I'd like to make it resilient against momentary blips in my internet connection, but I'm having a hard time.  When the connection fails, the blocking `Client.run()` that represents the normal bot operation finishes and closes the event loop.  I can't just re-call `Client.run()` a few minutes later, because The Event Loop is Closed.

I've tried re-declaring the Client object, but this doesn't seem to use a new event loop.  I'm going through the discord.py and python event loop documentation, but can't figure out how to get a new event loop and use that instead.

I've tried things along the lines of `asyncio.set_event_loop(asyncio.new_event_loop())` but it doesn't seem to make any difference - I still can't re-call `Client.run()` because the event loop is closed.

Comment: The rewrite branch introduced some reconnection logic to `connect` (One of the coroutines that's called from `run`).  You might try switching to the rewrite branch early and see if that improves things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the existing event loop in case of an internet connection blip. Simply don't call `Client.run` which closes the event loop. Since `Client.run` is anyway a simple wrapper around `run_until_complete` that closes the event loop, you can write your own that doesn't do so. For example:

```
def run_client(client, *args, **kwargs):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    while True:
        try:
            loop.run_until_complete(client.start(*args, **kwargs))
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error", e)  # or use proper logging
        print("Waiting until restart")
        time.sleep(600)
```